# No foreach Display

Tags: php, loops, foreach

```
    <?php
        $pros_array_id= array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'paint_id');
    
        $productee = $productn->getData('paint');

            foreach($productee as $pro):

                if($pro['paint_id'] == $pros_array_id):
    ?>
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="imgTag">
                <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $pro['paint_image'] ?? 1; ?>" ></a>
            </td>
        </tr> 
        </table>  
 
    <?php
        endif;
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

```
Am trying to display session cart items and its not showing anything. When I print_r($productee) and print_r($pros_array_id) after the foreach statement both display the accurate data, yet nothing displat in the <tr> tag.
```

The  is to display the result
When I implode $pros_array_id like this "$imp = implode(" ",$pros_array_id);" and put the variable  in the if-statement, it works fine if only one product is in the session, but the moment I add more than one products in the session, nothing is display again.
Please can someone point to me what I should do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<table>
<?php
  $pros_array_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'paint_id');
  $productee = $productn->getData('paint');

  foreach($productee as $pro) {
    //Also see and try to disable this check to see if it works then!
    if($pro['paint_id'] == $pros_array_id) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="imgTag">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $pro['paint_image'] ?? 1; ?>"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    }
  }  
?>
</table>
```

Always make sure while debugging this kind of code to eliminate any checks that could result in false, so try disabling the "if clause" as well, to see if it displays something then.

Comment: It still didn't display anything. . When I print_r() after the if-statement nothing is printed out. When I print_r($pro) after the foreach statement, it displayed all items in the paint table, but when I print_r(pros_array_id) which is the session cart item, it displayed this "Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) ",  yet no display in the <tr> tag.

Comment: So the data of $pros_array_id is everywhere equal to '7'? Because that would indicate your ```array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'paint_id');``` is simply not working. What is the value of $_SESSION['cart']?

Comment: Am sorry about the duplication, its my enter key that got stuck. the value is Array ( [0] => 7 ). and $_SESSION['cart'] is Array ( [0] => Array ( [paint_id] => 7 ) )